# tcpdump Server Hello Certificate Filter

Tags: ssl, tcpdump

On a devices located between my local network and a router, (all the traffic pass through) I need to read the common name from Hello Server Certificate packet.

So I'm trying to figure out how to get the proper filter with tcpdump.

I found help from this paper : http://www.wains.be/pub/networking/tcpdump_advanced_filters.txt
 It explain how to  use advance filter on IP and TCP fields.

I tried this kind of filter :

```
$ tcpdump -i any \
  'tcp and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' \
   -A -s 0 -v | grep 'Host\|id-at-commonName='
```

As explained in the paper, "We are matching any packet that contains data."

It works for the `Host` field as for many other data, but I can't match the field `id-at-commonName=` which is in SSL field (so in the TCP Data field ?).

To be sure I captured a pcap file with the exact same filter (without the grep) and when I open it with Wireshark, I can get every Certificate Common name. I must use a `tcpdump` filter because I need to get the data "on the fly".

Can someone explain why I can't see this data through `tcpdump`?

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to get the SSL Handshake Hello packet to see the contained SNI, the following filter seems to work for both TLS1.0 and TLS1.2 :

```
tcpdump -i any -s 1500 (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2)+5:1] = 0x01) and (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):1] = 0x16)
```

where 0x16 = Handshake (22)    at the first byte field of the data

and   0x01 = Client Hello (1)  at the 6th byte field of the data

Comment: I had to adjust the statement `tcpdump -i any -s 1500 '(tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2)+5:1] = 0x01) and (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):1] = 0x16)'`

Comment: It's worth noting the client is who initiated the conversation, and per the standard in "client hello" `0x01` the client tells the server its minimum supported version. The server eventually responds with a "server hello" `0x02` with the version it selected to use.

Answer (score 3):

The `id-at-commonName` label is shown by Wireshark, the wire format does not contain the text, but raw bytes. The name `id-at-commonName` is [`03` in bytes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-112). Following that, there is a UTF8String (12 = 0x0c) with a length of 9 bytes (`localhost`).

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

If you are trying to match host names from a TCP stream, keep the following in mind:

- Certificates may be valid for multiple subjects, you may find additional names in `id-ce-subjectAltName` (2.5.29.17)
- The real host that you are trying to connect to may be advertised in ClientHello handshake message via the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension.
- Multiple messages may be combined in a single record.

Finally, note that the SSL messages may be split over multiple TCP segments, making direct analysis even harder. Perhaps it is an option to capture to write a fixed count of packets to file with rotation enabled, manually parse with tshark afterwards, and finally remove the capture?

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Nathan Chan, since I cannot comment due to no enough reputation, add parameters '-nnXSs0 -ttt' to make it readable.

```
tcpdump -i any -s 1500 '(tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2)+5:1] = 0x01) and (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):1] = 0x16)' -nnXSs0 -ttt
```